# Manipulating unrendered DOM elements for export in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, dom

I created an Angular service to export an SVGElement for the user. To put it simply, it builds an SVG and appends symbols to the `<defs>`. The service then returns this SVG to the component using a Promise, and the component copies it to the clipboard or exports it as a file.

My problem is that the exported SVG element is empty at the time the component tries to export it. If I insert a `setTimeout()` around the `resolve(svgElement)` in the service, it works.

How can I manipulate these dynamically generated DOM elements in a more synchronous manner? The SVG is never going to be rendered for the user.

Here is some simplified code to try and illustrate the functionality.

```js
\\ service.ts
public exportToSVG(ids: string[]): Promise<SVGElement> {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
      const defs = document.createElement('defs');

      ids.forEach(async id => {
         // use another method to get the symbol associated with the id
         const symbol = await this._getSymbolByString(id);
         defs.appendChild(symbol);
      });

      svg.appendChild(defs);
      resolve(svg);
   });
}

\\ component.ts
public copyToClipboard(ids: string[]) {
   this.myService.exportToSVG(ids).then(svg => {
      // this only copies `<svg><defs></defs></svg>`, unless a setTimeout is used
      this.clipboardService.copyFromContent(svg.outerHTML);
   });
}
```

Comment: The symbols are stored elsewhere, and this just grabs one by the string given, assume it returns an SVGSymbolElement

Comment: That code actually returns a Promise, I can edit the post. I probably simplified the provided code too much, but unfortunately can't provide too much more detail. I have tried multiple variations of `async... awaits` on the different pieces of code that return Promises, yet the only thing that seems to work is `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use innerHTML instead:

```
\\ component.ts
public copyToClipboard(ids: string[]) {
   this.myService.exportToSVG(ids).then(svg => {
      this.clipboardService.copyFromContent(svg.innerHTML);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has the asynchronous nature. When you apply the Foreach loop, angular do not wait for the response and execute the next operation, that's why you could not get the `defs` variable. You should put this code into the condition which is fired after foreach loop is completed.

```js
\\ service.ts
public exportToSVG(ids: string[]): Promise<SVGElement> {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
      const defs = document.createElement('defs');
      let lengthIds = is.length;
      let count = 0;

      ids.forEach(async id => {
         // use another method to get the symbol associated with the id
         const symbol = await this._getSymbolByString(id);
         defs.appendChild(symbol);
         count++;
      });
  
    // check length of total number of elements in array and its count
      if(count === lengthIds){
        svg.appendChild(defs);
        resolve(svg);
      }
     
   });
}

\\ component.ts
public copyToClipboard(ids: string[]) {
   this.myService.exportToSVG(ids).then(svg => {
      // this only copies `<svg><defs></defs></svg>`, unless a setTimeout is used
      this.clipboardService.copyFromContent(svg.outerHTML);
   });
}
```

So i think it would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by chaining Promises, not using async... await.